# PayPal: Getting unexpected error on page

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox

This error message is ridiculous. Can't understand what they want to say. Looks like some Java code exception.

When I click on **Pay** button, then the following error message pops up:

[image]

Error message page:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be an issue at PayPal server, file an MTS ticket with description at : https://www.paypal-techsupport.com/, then PayPal MTS team will get in touch with you.